# Refactor Backbone View code to eliminate repetition

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I've created a simple Backbone View for a filter that hides table elements based on which 'input' tags are clicked:

```
var Filter = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: "form",
events: {
    "click input[name='2013']" : "filter2013",
    "click input[name='2012']" : "filter2012"
},
filter2013: function() {
    $("tr:contains('2013-')").toggle();
},
filter2012: function() {
    $("tr:contains('2012-')").toggle();
},
render: function() {
    this.$el.html(JST['acquisitions/filter']);
    $("#filter-container").append(this.$el);
    return this;
}
});
```

Not elegant at all, especially if I want to add more 'input' elements, which will result in more custom functions in the View that repeat the code. Perhaps a for loop combined with jquery to find numbers (say 2013, 2012, 2011, and so on) within the webpage and generate events based on that. Or perhaps I'll need to take the events out of the View altogether.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a `class` to the `<input>`s, say `class="year"`, to make them easier to find and then bind to click events on `input.year` and grab the year out of the event's `currentTarget.name`. Something like this:

```
var Filter = Backbone.View.extend({
    // ...
    events: {
        "click input.year" : "filter_year"
    },
    filter_year: function(ev) {
        $("tr:contains('" + ev.currentTarget.name + "-')").toggle();
    },
    //...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It works. A couple of clarifications: 1. Why do you say having a `class="year"` makes it easier to find? Referencing the name attribute seems to work fine.

Comment: `class="year"` allows you to bind to the `<input>`s of interest with a single `'click input.year'`, the `name` attributes vary between `<input>`s so you'd have to set up multiple entries in `events`.